# Correct implementation of lock for semaphore?

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I'm not sure whether the following implementation is correct. My reason is that if the current thread is interrupted while it is waiting to be signaled, the `finally` block will be called, but because it's not holding the lock, an `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown. Did I implement a `try-finally` block correctly in this case or rather should one be implemented?

```
  public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    try {
      lock.lockInterruptibly();
      while (permits == 0) {
        condition.await();
      }
      permits--;
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Not correct, why not to use monitor?

Comment: ...do I dare point out that [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) already exists?

Comment: I'm implementing a semaphore using a `ReentrantLock` and a `Condition`. It's for an assignment.

Comment: @BJPeterDeLaCruz You should be informed that assignment you must do yourself without help of others, in otherwise it's treated as cheating.

Comment: @RomanC Thanks for the advice. Rest assured, I have done the assignment already. :) But I'm unsure about this case.

Comment: +1  I don't think this question should be closed.  It actually asks a different question on whether `IllegalMonitorStateException` will be thrown if the waiting thread is interrupted.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a home assignment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure that I understand problem correctly, but you should try-finally only **after the resource is allocated**

```
  public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly(); // allocate resource before try
    try {
      while (permits == 0) {
        condition.await();
      }
      permits--;
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
```

I do not know why do all schools, e.g. [Sun's official page on finally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html), advise allocating inside the try (so that you need `if(allocated) {release}`) in the finally clause. This is stupid IMO. Why does everybody advise allocation inside try?

Comment: My question is, what will happen if the thread gets interrupted after it releases the lock (while it's waiting for the number of permits to become available)? The code in the `finally` block will get called, but it's not holding the lock, so an exception will be thrown there. Is that correct?

Comment: I do not know but how do you call unlock if you do not hold the key after you acquired it? Doesn't successful result from lock means that you hold it throughout until unlock is called? What interrupts have to do with loosing the key? How do you release the lock before reaching the finally?

Answer (score 1):

A good question.  I was actually surprised by the result myself.

If an `InterruptedException` occurs the condition will stop `awaiting` and will then execute the `finally`. It will obvious not own the lock and propagate an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution?

```
  public void acquire() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    while (permits == 0) {
      condition.await();
    }
    try {
      permits--;
    }
    finally {
      lock.unlock();
    }
  }
```

When `await` returns, the current thread will have the lock. If it gets interrupted while it is waiting to be signaled by other threads (i.e. it does not have the lock), `acquire` will throw the `InterruptedException` back up to the caller.

Comment: `I'm satisfied with this solution:`  I'm not.  What happens if `InterruptedException` occurs during `condition.await()`.  How will the lock ever be `unlocked` in that case.

Comment: But according to the documentation, the lock is released when that method is called, correct? Or are you saying that the thread could be interrupted sometime in that method the millisecond before the lock is released?

Comment: Yes that's right.  Let's assume the thread has been interrupted after `lock.lockInterruptibly()` and before `condition.await()`.  In that case it still owns the lock, and any invocation on `await()` will immediately throw an exception and will not unlock.  In that case you run into a potential deadlock.